# Custom Json.NET serializer settings per type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am using an ApiController which uses the global HttpConfiguration class to specify the JsonFormatter settings.  I can globally set serialization settings as follows very easily:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

The problem is that not all settings apply to all types in my project.  I want to specify custom TypeNameHandling and Binder options for specific types that perform polymorphic serialization.

How can I specify JsonFormatter.SerializationSettings on a per-type or at the least on a per-ApiController basis?

Comment: For apicontroller based config, you can take a look at per-controller configuration feature: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/per-controller-configuration-in-webapi.aspx . this post is a old one, but most of the stuff should be relevant for the latest bits too.

Comment: I tried resorting to per-controller configuration using the IControllerConfiguration attribute like you have suggested.  The settings I am specifying in the Initialize function for the JsonFormatter are actually being re-used by requests and are being applied to other controllers.  I only applied the attribute to one particular controller.  This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on your comment above, following is an example of per-controller configuration:

```
[MyControllerConfig]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
```

---

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MyControllerConfigAttribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        //remove the existing Json formatter as this is the global formatter and changing any setting on it
        //would effect other controllers too.
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Remove(controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

        JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        formatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Insert(0, formatter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could point me in the right direction to make this argument work per Controller Method?