# JSon.Net how to have $type only for deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I used the $type properties in Json for the deserialization of inherited objects (to choose the correct object type in which to deserialize at runtime)

I do this using :

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings{ TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects}
```

this line is in the WebApiConfig file.

It works fine but I can't figure out how to restrict the $type only to the webservices who actually needs it (I only need it for one PUT and one POST). 
The $type is messing up the API results for the other webservices and I can't find some TypeNameHandling configuration nor some serialization option to avoid this.
Does anyone knows how to do that?
Cheers!

Comment: Do you need $type for the root object, or a nested object?

Comment: I need it for a nested object. at least for now ... I can still refactor and use it at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable type name handling on a nested object, you can attach [`[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_TypeNameHandling.htm) to the containing property, like so:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects)]
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

There's no builtin way to enable type name handling on a specific type, and so there's no builtin way to enable type name handling on the root object.  Instead, you could use the `EnableJsonTypeNameHandlingConverter` from [SignalR Typenamehandling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314638/signalr-typenamehandling) if you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help dbc. I had other issues during deserialization (using a OData.Delta object and the solution you proposed didn't actually fit completely the need.
I overcame the issue thanks to this post : [Custom Json.NET serializer settings per type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684925/custom-json-net-serializer-settings-per-type)
to have the $type customization only for a few webservices.